# Find and Replace with Regex in Notepad++ Using Wildcards

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following two lines as an example, that's part of a much larger data set.  The file is quote text qualified with a vertical bar column delimiter.  You have examples of too many quotes that are blowing up my import.

```
"BD 3 ML SYRINGE 18GX1-1/2""|"0"|""|"10"|"MISCELLANEOUS"
```

**For example:** `18GX1-1/2""|` **SHOULD BE:** `18GX1-1/2"|`

```
"BD 3 ML SYRINGE 25GX1""|"0"|""|"10"|"MISCELLANEOUS"
```

**For example:** `25GX1""|`**SHOULD BE:** `25GX1"|`

I can easily find all instances of the error in my file using regex with `[\w]""|`

But I cannot find the right expression to simply replace the duplicate double quote with a single dbl quote replacing all words found with the original expression.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Try `\w\K""\|` and replace with `"|`

Comment: Wiktor...I'll give this a shot too and let you know if it worked!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try find `"+([^"|]+)"+`, replace with `"\1"`:

Capture any sequence of characters other than `"` and `|`, where the sequence is surrounded by any number of `"`; replacing by the captured group in a single pair of quotes.

In general, the pattern `delimiter(non-delimiters)delimiter` is quite useful for delimited text searches.

For your test inputs

```
String 1: "BD 3 ML SYRINGE 18GX1-1/2""|"0"|""|"10"|"MISCELLANEOUS"
becomes:  "BD 3 ML SYRINGE 18GX1-1/2"|"0"|""|"10"|"MISCELLANEOUS"

String 2: "BD 3 ML SYRINGE 25GX1""|"0"|""|"10"|"MISCELLANEOUS"
becomes:  "BD 3 ML SYRINGE 25GX1"|"0"|""|"10"|"MISCELLANEOUS"
```

**Edit: handling delimiter inside quoted string and escaped double quote**

Although not mentioned in the question, I thought it may be good to also handle the delimiter and possibly also escaped double quote characters inside the quoted string

The search pattern `(^|\|)"+([^"]*)"+(?=\||$)` and replace pattern `\1"\2"` builds on the above, but permits `|` inside a quoted string

```
String 3: "BD 3 ML SYRINGE 25GX1""|"0"|""|"10"|""MISCELL|ANEOUS""
becomes:  "BD 3 ML SYRINGE 25GX1"|"0"|""|"10"|"MISCELL|ANEOUS"
```

The search pattern `(^|\|)"+(([^"\\]|\\.)*)"+(?=\||$)` and replace pattern `\1"\2"` further permits escaped double quotes `\"` inside the quoted string

```
String 4: "6\" Tube""|"0"|""|"10"|""MISCELL|ANEOUS""
becomes:  "6\" Tube"|"0"|""|"10"|"MISCELL|ANEOUS"
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  I definitely was thinking to specific, and not broad enough.  As I am new to regular expressions, this really also helped me get a better understanding.  GREAT Answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a regular expression to do this. Why don't you just type `""` into the `find` and `"` into the `replace`.  I tried it on your example input:

```
"BD 3 ML SYRINGE 18GX1-1/2""|"0"|""|"10"|"MISCELLANEOUS"
```

[image]

Output:

```
"BD 3 ML SYRINGE 18GX1-1/2"|"0"|"|"10"|"MISCELLANEOUS"
```

Comment: I would further add that if OP intends to retain items consisting of empty double quotes (as in the middle item of `|"0"|""|"10"|`), this can be done by subsequently replacing `|"|` with `|""|`

Comment: Well chrisz because if you re-read and look closer at my example you'll find double, double quotes that are supposed to be there in the data set.   The regular expression is needed to find the anomalies in the data to be corrected.  The wildcard is needed because only alpha numeric characters will precede the errors.

Comment: Samantha unfortunately this is an entire data set.   It's not "static".  Empty fields can exist at any point.   I can't simply replace like that for an entire data set.